# How do i testfor a item a player is holding?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to `testfor` a player holding a diamond sword named `Notch's Legendary Sword`. How can I do that? Who ever gets the best answer will be able to get the first look at my NEW adventure map!

Comment: /testfor @p[r=10] {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",tag:{display:{Name:"Item Name"}}}}

Answer (score 4):

The `SelectedItem` compound holds a copy of the player's currently-held item. If you need to target the player after finding them, you should **not** use `/testfor` because that does not mark matching players for you to target afterwards.

You should instead use a command such as `/scoreboard` to assign a label, either a score in pre-1.9 or a "tag" in 1.9+:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=HoldingItem] remove HoldingItem
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=!HoldingItem] add HoldingItem {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",tag:{display:{Name:"Notch's Legendary Sword"}}}}
```

You would then be able to target the specific players holding the item:

```
/say @a[tag=HoldingItem]
```

Comment: I agree. `/testfor` is mostly useless.

Answer (score 1):

If it has a custom name you may not need to test for the diamond sword just the custom name: You could use a command like this: `/testfor @p[r=1000] {SelectedItemSlot:0,Inventory:[{Slot:0b,­tag:{display:{Name:"Notch's Legendary Sword"}}}]}`  This will testfor the the player holding the custom named item in slot 0.  You may choose to have the radius if you would like.

If you wish to know more watch this video on testfor:

*By Dragnoz*

This is a picture of the numbered slots you can use for reference when testing for an item in that slot:[image]

Answer (score 0):

As @Sean said, you can type:

> /testfor @a {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",tag:{display:{Name:"Notch's Legendary Sword"}}}}

This will test for all (`@a`) players HOLDING a diamond sword (`minecraft:diamond_sword) named Notch's Legendary Sword

@Jason_ 's command only works in command blocks. If you choose to use the command in command blocks, I suggest using @p as well.

If you want to do this globally I would suggest @a[c=1] (as in 1 command block to rule them all)

Comment: I see your point nice catch.

Comment: @p will only select the nearest one

Comment: @sharpturn um.. duh. My point is that in command blocks, if you test for everyone you would need to assign them a scoreboard profile, but with @p, you can just effect the player who stepped on a pressure plate (if you built the command blocks in the correct positions).

Comment: Yup, since the OP is going on and on about how he wants the player too have to step on a pressure plate. The "Rookie" in your username is more accurate than I ever could have imagined.

Comment: 'adventure map' - So  using logic (cough cough) he will want the user to power it and if anything you should use @[c=1] if you are doing it globally.

Comment: You... i cant even... for one @[c=1] is invalid, for two, why does it make any difference that it's an adventure map?

Comment: `@a[c=1]` is essentially the same as `@p` with the difference of targeting dead players, and doesn't really solve anything. With the mechanics available these days, custom maps these days don't (and shouldn't) rely on lag-incuding physical redstone logic, for both the lag and the lack of multiplayer support. The OP did not say anything about only targeting a player based on a pressure plate. Ideally answers should be multiplayer-friendly and cover as many situations as possible (unless clarified by OP), which is not possible with basic `/testfor` commands.

Comment: @a[c=1] is arguably more useful than @p in the execute command beacause @p will always select the closest person. Also,  the author EXPLICITLY says he needs a testfor command. Your technique, while more useful, is only avaliable in 1.9 If you really think my answer is useless and does not help in anway, you can use the down vote button.

Comment: It's AT not AD at beginning